How to export images from videos in supervisely?
I am trying to export annotated images from videos in supervisely (coco, supervisely format) to import my annotated data to this Colab Project
https://colab.research.google.com/github/Kazuhito00/YOLOX-Colaboratory-Training-Sample/blob/main/YOLOX_Colaboratory_Training_Sample.ipynb
I have no download "in supervisely format" that they describe in their docs. What am I doing wrong?
enter image description here
I labeled videos with one class. I read the docs and I don't have the button that they describe there.
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

contact authors of "supervisely" for product support
